# how can add new filed to custom module that inherited sale.order.line module?

Tags: xml, inheritance, odoo-9

Iam new in Odoo-9.0c, I have tried to create a custom module, that includes some fields, and for new purpose I want to add 1 more fileds.Char to that module. this is the code of new field.

```
    @api.multi
    def _get_show_name(self):
        for order_line in self:
            if order_line.product_id: 
                if oder_line.width_id:
                    if order_line.width_id.id == ids in range(12):
                        order_line.show_name = '%d - %d' % (order_line.product_id.id(name), order_line.widt$
                    else:
                        order_line.show_name = '%d' % (order_line.product_id.id(name))

show_name = fields.Char(compute=get_show_name, string='new name')
```

width_id is a many2one field that has been created in my custom module.

Please give me a hand to check the above code and show me how can I add this field to sale.xml. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

There is mistake on following line. *ids* variable not declared.

```
if order_line.width_id.id == ids in range(12):
```

You can try with following code to add field in *sale.xml* view file

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="view_sale_order_extend_form">
    <field name="name">view.sale.order.extend.form</field>
    <field name="model">sale.order</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_order_form"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">

        <!-- Add show_name field in Sale order line tree view-->
        <xpath expr="//field[@name='order_line']/tree//field[@name='product_id']" position="after">
            <field name="show_name"/>
        </xpath>

        <!-- Add show_name field in Sale order line form view-->
        <xpath expr="//field[@name='order_line']/form//field[@name='product_id']" position="after">
            <field name="show_name"/>
        </xpath>

    </field>
</record>
```

Comment: Thank you for replying, i will try to rewrite the module and give you the feedback thanks:d

Comment: i got the error with sentence: for order_line in self: ? do you have any idea?

Comment: There is no mistake on  that line. But make sure you have added that field and method in *sale.order.line* object.

Comment: your mean i need to put the field at the same class that has already inherited form sale.order.line, instead of creating a new inherited class

Comment: You have written wrong variable name. Its *order_line* not *oder_line*. Improve following line *if oder_line.width_id:* with *if order_line.width_id:*

Comment: i have done to fix the varibles name but some show the error keep maintaining

Comment: in My case could you please show me the right way de declare variable ?